# Does ANTLR allow multiple variable definitions in the locals clause?

Tags: antlr4

in a Parser Grammar I'd like to define several variables in the
`locals` clause.

A simplified example looks like this:

```
body
locals [
    Map<String, String> bodyContent = new HashMap<String, String>();
    long counter = 0;
]
            :   BODY_CAPTION NEWLINE line ;
line        :   key='MyKey' TAB value='MyValue' NEWLINE
                {
                    $body::bodyContent.put($key.text, $value.text);
                    $body::counter++;
                } ;
```

This gives the error:

`unknown attribute 'counter' for rule 'body' in '$body::counter'`

If I swap the lines in the `locals` clause like this

```
locals [
    long counter = 0;
    Map<String, String> bodyContent = new HashMap<String, String>();
]
```

it gives the error:

`unknown attribute 'bodyContent' for rule 'body' in '$body::bodyContent'`

Apparently, ANTLR recognizes only the first local variable definition in the `locals` clause.

Is there a way, to define multiple local variables under `locals`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but they are comma separated like the parameter list and `returns` clause.

```
locals [
    Map<String, String> bodyContent = new HashMap<String, String>(),
    long counter = 0
]
```