# antlr4 grammar-locals clause doesn't generate variable declaration in Parser

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934081/antlr4-matching-all-input-alternatives-exaclty-once?answertab=active#tab-top) I made my rule like:

```
ompParallel
  locals [java.util.HashSet<String> names = new java.util.HashSet<String>();]
  : SOME_LEXER_CONSTANT modifiers ;

modifiers
//Ensure that the full number of modifiers have been provided
: {$ompParallel::names.size() < 3}? predicateModifier modifiers
| {$ompParallel::names.size() == 3}? //match nothing once we have (any) three modifiers
;

predicateModifier
//Ensure that no duplicates have been provided
: {!$ompParallel::names.contains("a")}? A {$ompParallel::names.add("a");}
| {!$ompParallel::names.contains("b")}? B {$ompParallel::names.add("b");}
| {!$ompParallel::names.contains("c")}? C {$ompParallel::names.add("c");}
;
```

but in generated Parser there is only

```
public java.util.HashSet<String> names;
```

without declaration `= new java.util.HashSet<String>();`.

According to last snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110010/rule-variables-in-antlr4?answertab=active#tab-top) I tried something like

```
ruleName
  @init {
      java.util.HashSet<String> names = new java.util.HashSet<String>();
  }
  : SOME_LEXER_CONSTANT modifiers ;
```

This led to grammar-compilation error

```
 unknown attribute names for rule ompParallel in $ompParallel::names
```

I am really confused, could someone help me out? Preferably fixin the first alternative (using `locals [...]`.

**EDIT1:** [related source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644200/does-antlr-allow-multiple-variable-definitions-in-the-locals-clause)

Comment: Try to remove the `;` in your first attempt just before the `]`. If that doesn't work, as a workaround you could try to combine both approaches: declare the variable with `locals [java.util.HashSet<String> names]` and init it with `@init { names = new java.util.HashSet<String>(); }` but... meh.

Comment: The former solution didn't help, nevertheless the letter did (with some tweaks, please see my answer below) thanks! Anyway I consider this a problem and I'll try to report it to some issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to [@Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3764814/lucas-trzesniewski) I figured it out:

```
ompParallel    
locals [static java.util.HashSet<String> names]
@init {
    OmpParallelContext.names = new java.util.HashSet<String>();
}
: PARALLEL modifiers ;
```

One needs to define the variable `static`ally in order to access it from different class. Unfortunately ANTLR4 generated Parser code seems to be little clumsy.

Comment: anyway one should be very careful when using `static` in recursive rules